# How to run some testcases in parallel and some serially in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a few hundreds of tests and I want some of them to run in parallel, and some to run serially, within the same run.

I am aware how to run them all parallelly, or all serially, but not combined.

Is there any way to do this in pytest?

Comment: You might need to develop your own plugin for that using pytest hooks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to achieve this using the `pytest-xdist` plugin specifying `--dist` with `loadscope`, `loadfile`, or `loadgroup`.

Refer to the docs for details: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/#running-tests-across-multiple-cpus

Answer (score 0):

You can run it with `--dist loadgroup` and use `@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group_serial")` annotation on every test that must run serially. From the [documentation](https://pytest-xdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distribution.html), this will make sure that tests with the `group_serial` mark "... will run in the same worker. Tests without the xdist_group mark are distributed normally as in the --dist=load mode.". And the `--dist=load` mode distributes tests accross all workers.

An advantage of running it like this is that you can still run the entire test collection in just one pytest execution, and then your coverage report will still encompass your entire test collection.

Note: This answer expands on the answer given by @Teejay Bruno